# I can't add pgsql PDO Driver in MAMP on Mac Big Sur

Tags: postgresql, mamp, psql, php-pgsql

I have installed MAMP and PostgreSQL with PGAdmin4, but I'm having some problems.

I'm getting a psql "command not found error" in my terminal. I have added `export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/10/bin:$PATH` into `~/.bash_profile`, but whenever I reopen the terminal, I get the same error again.

Whenever I try to execute `composer` or `php artisan` in my Laravel project I get the below errors, but I'm still able to migrate database:

`Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/pdo_pgsql (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/pdo_pgsql, 9): image not found)`

`Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pgsql' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/pgsql (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/pgsql, 9): image not found)`

Getting a "driver not found" error whenever trying to browse the project and in `PDO Drivers` list in `phpinfo()`, mysql and sqlite available, but pgsql is not available.

MAMP
PostgreSQL 10
PHP: 7.3.21
OS: MAC Big Sur

Comment: Did you sort this out? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Any solutions? I'm having the same issue. Its working fine on my machine running Catalina. But on Big Sur it couldn't load.

Comment: For me downgrading from MAMP 6, to MAMP 5.7 worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and when I looked in my `php.ini` file, I saw that my extensions folder was pointed to the wrong location:

`extension_dir = "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/lib/php/extensions"`

But I don't have a matching directory for php7.4.2 - I use php7.4.9, and confirmed the extension exists in that folder.  To fix it for me, I just had to change the above line in my `php.ini` file to:

`extension_dir = "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.9/lib/php/extensions"`

And then all was good for me.

Comment: In my situation altering the extension_dir in php.ini did the trick. thank you.